# Domain Server through windows 7?

Tags: windows, domain

is it possible to run a AD DS through a regular windows 7 workstation?

Answer (score 3):

In a word, no.

Windows 7 does not come with the required libraries and services needed to deploy AD. Even if it did, it's a workstation operating system and should not be used to provide services to other computers.